# True or false: If $S, T \in L(V, V)$, then $\det(S + T) = \det(S) + \det(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or give a counterexample: If $S, T \in L(V, V)$, then $\det(S + T ) = \det(S) + \det(T)$.

I'm not really sure how to go about proving this please help?

Comment: $S=I_2,T=-I_2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

$\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \neq \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \det \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$